# Dynamically creating tables based on data for year and quarter

Tags: ssis

I am trying to store approximately 11 billion records in the destination table by querying various source tables via inner join.

I would need to store the data based on Year and Quarter. There is a need to store data from year 2000 onward.

So I would have tables for e.g

```
FinData2015_1
FinData2015_2
FinData2015_3
FinData2015_4


FinData2016_1
FinData2016_2
FinData2016_3
FinData2016_4
```

I planned to create the physical tables right from year 2000 to 50 years from now and implement a split condition component in SSIS.
So I would create in all 67 tables in all and 67 split conditions

See the screenshot below

[image]

Is there a better way to do this. That is creating table dynamically if data for that year and quarter exist

Comment: Why do you want different tables for different years?  This is exactly what table partitioning was created for...

Comment: Yes there's a better way - table partitioning. You haven't explained why you are actually doing this. You can store that many records in one table. What will you be doing once they're in there - reporting? What kind of queries? summaries or detail?

Comment: I have tried table partitioning and for some reason creating bigger foot print. I would like to try the split component approach and see if its the best way of doing it by manually creating 50 splits

Comment: How did you originally define the table partitioning?  Did you apply something similar to that defined in this link?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes

Comment: Yes . Had taken the same script and modified table names and server names to the ones I use

Comment: The sizes I defined were in gigs. Would that be the reason. Do I need to specify the sizes as mentioned in the example and that will grow accordingly

Comment: Another thing to note is that the same query took 14 hours to dump in non partitioned table but took 44 hours to to dump records in partioned table