# insert into select not working using linked server

Tags: sql-server

I have written a script to insert data into a destination server by reading data from the source server. For some reason it doesn't insert the data into the destination table. Is there anything wrong with the query

```
insert into [GBIPS-I-DB324D].[CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_1] 
select fp.calendarYear, fp.calendarQuarter, fp.companyid, fd.dataitemid, fd.dataitemvalue, fp.fiscalyear, fp.fiscalquarter, fi.periodenddate, fi.filingdate, fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag, fi.latestfilingforinstanceflag
                                 from [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinPeriod] fp
                                 inner join [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinInstance] fi on fi.financialPeriodId = fp.financialPeriodId
                                 inner join [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinInstanceToCollection] fc on fc.financialInstanceId = fi.financialInstanceId
                                 inner join [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinCollection] c on c.financialCollectionId = fc.financialCollectionId
                                 inner join [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinCollectionData] fd on fd.financialCollectionId = c.financialCollectionId
                                 where YEAR(fi.periodenddate) = 2000 and  DATEPART( quarter,fi.periodenddate)  = 1
```

Comment: What error do you get? Do you get results if you comment out the `INSERT INTO` line?

Comment: There is no error. Yes I get results when i run the select

Comment: if I do the following it works insert into [GBIPS-I-DB324D].[CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_1] 
values(2000,1,668679,407,'20000331.000000',2000,1,'2000-03-31 00:00:00.000','2001-05-15 00:00:00.000',1,1)

Comment: I tried including the columns but that doesn't work as well

Comment: Dude don't do this - don't create a table for every year / quarter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137132/dynamically-creating-tables-based-on-data-for-year-and-quarter. Regardless. Your question doesn't make sense. Whats the problem? Can't see data in the target table?

Comment: We need to do this because I am transmitting 12 billions rows and we are breaking it into smaller tables so that the retrieval is faster. This is alternative approach to table partitioning but with table partitioning , I noticed that the data storage is bigger

Comment: "so that the retrieval is faster" - finally you state a problem! So how do you retrieve the data? Do you have specific queries in mind? If you go with this design you _might_ improve performance but it's then an ongoing maintenance nightmare to have to shuffle data around certain tables, pick the correct table etc. I don't see why table partitioning would require more data storage? Even if it did, again the cost of storage is miniscule compared to the cost of all the fiddling you are going to have to do in future to maintain this.

Comment: Hi Nick , the same query was using 4 TB to store the data in partitioned tables as compared to 1 TB with non partitoned.  Isnt that significant

Comment: That's very significant... and unexpected. How did you work that size out? Did you use `sys.allocation_units` ? Anyway... we're still not sure if partitioning will help with your queries, I just know that the table design you propose is a maintenance nightmare, and I don't know what problem you're trying to solve